# Limit references to public fields in a project

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains only a number of public constant strings. As a developer I only want them to be referenced a maximum of once in my project. Is there a way to place an attribute on the consts or some other mechanism to cause the compiler to generate an error if more than one reference to each const is found?

I 'could' of course use private consts in each respective consuming class, but I'd like them all in one file for maintainability purposes and it seemed like an interesting question.

Comment: Why you need public const fields, if you are going to refer them only once ?? why not use constant values in your code.

Comment: I want all the consts in one class for maintainability. I really want to avoid 'hard-coded' strings in lots of classes, and would prefer to not have private consts in lots of classes.

Comment: What is the purpose of the constants?  Would your need be better served with configuration settings?

Comment: The constants are returned by the getter of a public property on a series of viewmodels in an MVVM project. These properties are not bound to by any view / UI and never will be, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have in mind to implement this **bad** pattern is to keep the logic of private const fields and store them in a single file containing [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) declarations for each related class.

Example:

```
public partial class MyClass1
{
    private const string myClass1Const1 = "myClass1Const1";
    private const string myClass1Const2 = "myClass1Const2";
}

public partial class MyClass2
{
    private const string myClass2Const1 = "myClass2Const1";
    private const string myClass2Const2 = "myClass2Const2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for a constant to be used no more than one time leads down the path of the constant should be private and only defined in the class or method that needs the value.

There may be other ways to accomplish the behavior of a single source file for the constants and they can only be used once, but here is one option. Although, I really wouldn't recommend it; use it if you must.

```
public static class Consts
{
    private const string _name = "Foo";
    private static int _nameCount = 0;

    public static string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if( _nameCount++ > 1 )
            {
                throw new Exception( "Cannot use Name more than once." );
            }
            return _name;
        }
    }
}
```